# Fullscreen map with Semantic UI

Tags: css, leaflet, semantic-ui

I'm trying to display a semantic-ui sidebar AND full-screen map.

The deal is I will construct map events to toggle the sidebar(s). My problem is with the CSS.

I'm able to show everything as expected, but I'm having the first item on the menu always shown, pushing a lot of stuff down.

This is the relevant html structure:

```
<body>
<div class="ui sidebar vertical menu">
    <a class="item">
        Item 1
    </a>
    <a class="item">
        Item 2
    </a>
    <a class="item">
        Item 3
    </a>
</div>

<div class="pusher">
    <div id="map"></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/semantic/dist/semantic.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/leaflet/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<script>
    var map = L.map('map').setView([51.505, -0.09], 13);
    $('.ui.sidebar').sidebar('toggle');
</script>
</body>
```

Here are the changes I did to CSS:

```
body {
background-color: #FFFFFF;
display: flex;
height: 100vh;
flex-direction: column;
}

#map {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
}
```

An example of how this is behaving, as the page loads, and after the toggle:

[image: As the page loads]

[image: After toggle]

Answer (score 1):

Giving the pusher a height of 100% should solve the problem.

```
<body>
  <div class="ui right sidebar" id="side_content">
    THIS IS IT
  </div>
  <!-- Search bar for the map -->
  <div class="pusher" style="height:100%">
  <div id="map"></div>
</div>
</body>
```

Referenced from: [Issue 1664](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/issues/1664)

Answer (score -1):

try this

```html
<body>
  
<style>
  .unstyle{
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.0)!important;
}
</style>

<div id="topbar" style="width: 100%; height: 37px;" class="">
  <button id="btn"> toggle</button>
  <button style="float: right"> toggle</button>
</div>
<div id="app" class="" style="height: 94%; width: 100%">
  <div class="ui left vertical menu sidebar unstyle"></div>
  <div class="pusher" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;">
    <div id="mapid"  style="height: 100%; width: 100%; position: relative;"> </div>
  </div>
  <script>
  $('#app .ui.sidebar')
   .sidebar({context: $('#app')})
   .sidebar('setting','transition', 'overlay')
   .sidebar('setting','dimPage', false)
   .sidebar('setting','closable', false)
   .sidebar('attach events', '#btn')
   .sidebar('toggle');
  </script>
</div>

</body>
```

[image: result screenshot]